# YouTube Data API V3 Beginner Guidance

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to develop a website using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for my youtuber friends. This website uses the YouTube Data API V3. Moreover, while I was coding and using the API, I have reached my quota limit for today which is the 10,000 quotas per day because from what I have read the quota cost per call for the Search: list *(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)* is 100 quotas. There are several questions that have been answered. However, as a beginner in web development I am getting overwhelmed on the terms they are mentioning.

**The questions are:**

1. How do I optimize the method calls for the Search: list from the YouTube Data API V3?

- *I have 26 images that has a function that every time I click the image, there will be a fetch to an API (Search: List Method). Say, I would click each image it would already cost 2,600 quotas, and that is not good for making a website for public usage.*

2. Is it possible to get the latest video of different YouTube channels at the same time using YouTube Data API V3? If yes, how do I do it?

- *I have a section on the website that plans to display all the latest video upload of each of the YouTube channels. For a better reference on what I am planning to do is by checking out the "latest" tab on this website https://hermitcraft.com*

3. Should I request for an increase quota limit if I am doing such project?

**What I tried:**

(1.) question:

```
function getChannelAPI(channelName, channelID){

    var url = "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId="+channelID+"&maxResults=5&order=date&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]"

fetch(url)
    .then((result) => {
        return result.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        //rest of the code
    })
```

This is the code that I have tried using for each of the image. It is working as expected. However, I think there is still a way of optimizing this.

I hope you guys understand my questions. I am in my 3rd year college majoring in Computer Science, I am not a professional programmer. I may not be able to understand the answers quickly, but I will try my best to learn and understand things.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the restrictions on this API are ridiculous. [Read this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits). It's a pretty crummy API anyway. The only way you'll get around these restrictions is to request public HTML pages and scrape them -- using regular expressions to extract the data you want. Beware, though, if YouTube changes the UI your application is likely to break.